# Using recent blockhash with Python

Tags: solana-program, python, blockhash

How can I add the getLatestblockhash function in to this code.

I tried it but I got:

**TypeError: argument 'blockhash': 'GetLatestBlockhashResp' object cannot be converted to 'Hash'**

````
from spl.token.client import Token
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from solders.system_program import TransferParams, transfer
from solana.transaction import Transaction

mint = Pubkey.from_string(
    "Gh9ZwEmdLJ8DscKNTkTqPbNwLNNBjuSzaG9Vp2KGtKJr"
)  # eg: https://solscan.io/token/FpekncBMe3Vsi1LMkh6zbNq8pdM6xEbNiFsJBRcPbMDQ**
program_id = Pubkey.from_string(
    "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
)  # eg: https://solscan.io/account/**TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA**

privkey = "6614rQjZYrcUL8YtNQ8vcf.......VM8hJwgMPnSPdBRGHSxxroJLn"
key_pair = Keypair.from_base58_string(privkey)

solana_client = Client("https://api.devnet.solana.com")
spl_client = Token(
    conn=solana_client, pubkey=mint, program_id=program_id, payer=key_pair
)

source = Pubkey.from_string("BAPkhTqGe4Squ8hH71QzixhTcfhJv7Lb8SvV7To5gzPg")
dest = Pubkey.from_string("3ApghjTLzyAfBvq9z1kQkfTp5puoZHsKZZ9ziwBvR8T1")

try:
    source_token_account = (
        spl_client.get_accounts_by_owner(
            owner=source, commitment=None, encoding="base64"
        )
        .value[0]
        .pubkey
    )
    
except:
    source_token_account = spl_client.create_associated_token_account(
        owner=source, skip_confirmation=False, recent_blockhash=None
    )
    
try:
    dest_token_account = (
        spl_client.get_accounts_by_owner(owner=dest, commitment=None, encoding="base64")
        .value[0]
        .pubkey
    )
    
except:
    dest_token_account = spl_client.create_associated_token_account(
        owner=dest, skip_confirmation=False, recent_blockhash=None
    )

amount = 10

txn = Transaction()

transaction = spl_client.transfer(
    source=source_token_account,
    dest=dest_token_account,
    owner=key_pair,
    amount=int(float(amount) * 100000),
    multi_signers=None,
    opts=None,
    recent_blockhash=None,
)

print(transaction)```
````

Answer (score 0):

`GetLatestBlockhashResp` contains more than just the blockhash, so you simply need to extract it:

```
blockhash = solana_client.get_latest_blockhash().value.blockhash
```

Here's the source code, for reference: https://github.com/kevinheavey/solders/blob/16656d9e508c5ed9bd237fd94a1c7bfa45eef9be/python/solders/rpc/responses.pyi#L711

Next time, be sure to add the failing code, since it's tough to tell what's wrong without the call to `get_latest_blockhash`.